# HTTP Post body size limit on client side

Tags: http

Is there a way a client can limit the http post body size..

Here is the what is happening -

1. From one of the machines, I can only upload a file of size upto 4
   kb. Anything more than that, results in the server returning **Http
   400** - Bad Http Request..
   I cannot FTP a big file as well.
2. It is not a server issue for sure because a lot of other clients are uploading files of 2gb.
3. This is happening only for that particular machine. I do not own
       that machine but have sudo access. Is it because of a proxy sitting
       in from of the machine?

Can any one tell how to debug this?

Comment: If it's not a server issue, why is the server returning an error code?

Comment: It sounds like the client isn't sending a proper `Content-Length` header. Have you looked at the request headers that it's sending, and compared the succeeding and failing requests?